# How to use regex to find all array declarations in C files?

Tags: c++, c, regex, grep

I am trying to analyse some third party code and I am interested in all arrays that are declared+defined in the given source (.c and .h). This is interesting to know if some memory is wasted when porting to an embedded system.

I can assume that only standard types are used, i.e. char, int, long, float, double.

Here is an example of what I want to find:

```
char message[100];
int tag[MY_PERSONAL_TAG_SIZE];
double vald[2]   ={1.0,1.1};
```

I have tried the following with the great support of a colleague but it gets some false positives:

```
egrep -e '(char|int|long|short|float|double)[ \t]*[^ \t)]+[ \t]*\[[^ \t]+\]' *
```

This also finds (which it shouldn't):

```
wordTable  = &intTable[0];
MyFunction (MyPointer* foo, int *bar, int code[4], int add[4], char *Mystring[4]) {
```

I guess the regex also finds some other false positives and might miss some definitions it should find. So I would be happy to hear any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't generally possible to do without generating false positives. There is also a little ambiguity in your question. (For example, `char *Mystring[4]` in the last line: do you count it as an array declaration or not? I mean, it *is* declaring a statically-allocated array, but it's also in a parameter list.)

Comment: Also, your regex in the line starting with `egrep -e ...` won't work if the array is of a non-primitive type, so you're also getting false negatives.

Comment: You are not going to be able to use regex to find all arrays in C or C++ source code. There are grammar constructs in C and C++ which regex simply cannot handle. Instead you want a tool like clang-query: http://reviews.llvm.org/D2098

Comment: Just as a simple example of something your regex will not handle: `typedef int foo_t[100000];  foo_t my_array;` A regex might find the typedef, but then you'll have to do another search for `foo_t` everywhere. clang-query should be able to find all arrays, because it actually understands C and C++.

Comment: @bames53: its indeed not possible to handle struct and dynamic allocation memory. And egrep has only basic regex features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require some regex wizardry but it **will not be reliable enough**. You should use a proper C parser for such tasks.

But still, if you want to do it quick&dirty, here's a Perl (or Perl-compatible) regex that does the trick (it needs to be used with the `m` and `s` modifiers):

```
(?:\(.*\)|\/\*.*?\*\/)(*SKIP)(?!)|(?:^|[;,])\s*\K(?:char|int|long|short|float|double)(?:\s*\**\s*\w+\s*\[\w*\]\s*[=;,])+
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/hY6sV2/3

It ignores everything in comments or parentheses, and tries to find an array declaration at the start of a line or after a colon or semicolon.

Comment: @Casimir You're right, thanks. I actually addeed the `\K` at the very end to get cleanier matches.

Comment: Don't worry, I do the same mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest `clang-query` as an alternative to `regex`. Here's one example to show what `clang-query` can do.

Two files `test.h` and `test.cpp` similar to the question.

```
$ cat ~/CPP/test.h
 1  int x[10], y, z[10];

$ cat ~/CPP/test.cpp
 1  #include "test.h"
 2  
 3  #define MY_PERSONAL_TAG_SIZE 10
 4  
 5  struct MyPointer;
 6  
 7  void MyFunction (MyPointer* foo, int *bar, int code[4], int add[4], char *Mystring[4])
 8  {
 9  }
10   
11  int main()
12  {
13      char message[100];
14      int tag[MY_PERSONAL_TAG_SIZE];
15      double vald[2]   ={1.0,1.1}; 
16      int a[10], b, c[30];
17  
18      return 0;
19  }
```

Run `clang-query` with `test.cpp` and query array declarations.

```
$ ./clang-query ~/CPP/test.cpp --
clang-query> help
Available commands:

  match MATCHER, m MATCHER      Match the loaded ASTs against the given matcher.
  set bind-root (true|false)    Set whether to bind the root matcher to "root".
  set output (diag|print|dump)  Set whether to print bindings as diagnostics,
                                AST pretty prints or AST dumps.

clang-query> match varDecl(hasType(arrayType()))

Match #1:

~/CPP/test.h:1:1: note: "root" binds here
int x[10], y, z[10];
^~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

~/CPP/test.h:1:1: note: "root" binds here
int x[10], y, z[10];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #3:

~/CPP/test.cpp:13:5: note: "root" binds here
    char message[100];
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #4:

~/CPP/test.cpp:14:5: note: "root" binds here
    int tag[MY_PERSONAL_TAG_SIZE];
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #5:

~/CPP/test.cpp:15:5: note: "root" binds here
    double vald[2]   ={1.0,1.1}; 
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #6:

~/CPP/test.cpp:16:5: note: "root" binds here
    int a[10], b, c[30];
    ^~~~~~~~~

Match #7:

~/CPP/test.cpp:16:5: note: "root" binds here
    int a[10], b, c[30];
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7 matches.
clang-query>
```

Comment: I like the idea of having a real parser instead of just using regex. However, I don't really know how I can install clang-query (ubuntu or linuxmint). I have installed llvm and clang but I don't have clang-query. And by the way, is there a way to pass several files or a directory to clang-query?

Comment: I am not sure if the `clang-query` binary is available to download. I compiled it in Ubuntu as described [here](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). You should compile optional extra clang tools.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to pass several files. `USAGE: clang-query [options] <source0> [... <sourceN>]`

Comment: If you don't like to compile `clang-query`, you can try `clang-check` that binary can be found easier. Try `clang-check -ast-dump ~/CPP/test.cpp --` and check `VarDecl` lines.

Comment: clang-query can be obtained by using the official Apt repository from LLVM directly (http://llvm.org/apt/). It is a matter of minutes without any compilation until you have all the tools installed. It might be that the individual tools are suffixed with their version, e.g. "clang-query-3.6". Note, that the clang-query tool has autocompletion when you hit <TAB> and don't know what's available. I highly recommend you watch this video to get started with LLVM and the whole matchers thing. It is really not that complicated and much more expressive than regexes: http://youtu.be/VqCkCDFLSsc

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this regex:

```
\w+\s\w+\[\w+\](?!,)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pA7tZ4/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?:char|int|long|short|float|double)(?:\s+.*?)?\[.*?\].*?;
```

This regex matches the requirements, if:

- The array is of the type: char, int, long, short, float, double
- The Array declaration ends with ;